# how to make a non required parameter in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have different required parameters in flutter and I want to make one of them non required (colour). If I leave it without the `required` key, it give an error. How can I make it? Here is my code:

```
class DiscoverCardTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  DiscoverCardTemplate({
    required this.textTop,
    required this.textMiddle,
    required this.textBottom,
    required this.coverImage,
    required this.onTap,
    this.colour,
  });

  final String textTop, textMiddle, textBottom, coverImage;
  final Function onTap;
  final Color colour;
```

Comment: Simply remove `required`. This way you have to `initialize` the `variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it nullable means `colour` will be either null or colur_value.

```
class DiscoverCardTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  DiscoverCardTemplate({
    required this.textTop,
    required this.textMiddle,
    required this.textBottom,
    required this.coverImage,
    required this.onTap,
    this.colour,
  });

  final String textTop, textMiddle, textBottom, coverImage;
  final Function onTap;
  final Color? colour;
```

or

add a default value for `colour` (if you didn't pass `colour` then it uses default value).

```
class DiscoverCardTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  DiscoverCardTemplate({
    required this.textTop,
    required this.textMiddle,
    required this.textBottom,
    required this.coverImage,
    required this.onTap,
    this.colour = colour_value,
  });

  final String textTop, textMiddle, textBottom, coverImage;
  final Function onTap;
  final Color colour;
```

Comment: @Reagan Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Either make the

`final Color colour;`

as nullable:

`final Color? colour;`

Or, assign a default color in the constructor

`this.colour = Colors.black,`

Comment: How to make it nullable? I am a newbie in flutter

Comment: final Color? colour; add ? after the type